# PHP Storing/Retrieving image names in MySQL DB

Tags: php

I am currently working on a multiple image uploader with file directory. I am wanting to store file name inside my MySQL.

How can I store these variables(image names) inside my table through php ?

How can I retrieve the variables through php?

**URL Generate by uploader:**

- http://www.website.com/imageupload/index.php?i=4ff4bfd02c241.jpg
- http://www.website.com/imageupload/index.php?i=4ff4bfd02c242.jpg

**Filename:**

- 4ff4bfd02c241.jpg
- 4ff4bfd02c242.jpg

**Table Name:** urlimage

```
id: autoincrement
image_name
```

**I am able to echo out the path and the name through this:**

```
$images = explode(',', $_GET['i']);

$path = Configuration::getUploadUrlPath('medium', 'target');

foreach ($images as $image) {

    echo '<div><p>' . $path . $image . '</p><img src="' . $path . $image . '" /></div>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$images = explode(',', $_GET['i']);

$path = Configuration::getUploadUrlPath('medium', 'target');


if(is_array($images)){

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `urlimage` (`image_name`) VALUES ";

  foreach ($images as $image) {

    //echo '<div><p>' . $path . $image . '</p><img src="' . $path . $image . '" /></div>';
    $value[] = "(".$path.$image.")"; // collect imagenames
  }

  $sql .= implode(',', $value).";"; //build query

  //don't know how you send queries, you should use a kind of mysqli-functionality
  queryfunction($sql);   
}
```

Addiontally: you should think of using $_POST rather than $_GET becaus there's a length limit depending on the browser (some of them cut URLs after 255 chars).
Also never put in userdefined content directly into you DB. You'll need some kind of escaping ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php ).